# Is there a non-canon work that explores the effect of Vulcan's destruction in the Kelvin Timeline?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-2009, star-trek-reboot

It would be interesting to explore:

1. how the absence of Vulcan has altered the Federation
2. how the destruction of their planet tests the remaining Vulcan's commitment to the reverence of logic.

I am perturbed that J. J. Abrams made such a huge choice for apparently no reason.

Comment: There were some books scheduled, but they have been on hold since 2010.

Comment: I recall the events of the second movie (especially Admiral Marcus' project) was due to the need for a more militarized Starfleet in light of Vulcan's destruction. So I guess that movement toward militarization would be an example of (a).

Comment: the IDW comics are really the only medium other than the films themselves that are exploring that timeline

Comment: @NKCampbell - There is also some really unique and abominable fanfiction as well.